# Python logging doesn't work currently on google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging

I have a problem with logging in to google cloud it shows only an error log when this log is info. I found many solutions to solve my problem, like the need to use google cloud logging, but it does not help me and I still have the problem. Somebody can help me to solve my problem, please.

Sorry for my bad English.

logger file

```
"""Time logger
"""
import logging

import urllib3


urllib3.disable_warnings()


def setup_logger(name: str) -> logging.Logger:
    """Logger for time
    """
    logging.getLogger('waitress').setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    logger.handlers.clear()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create console handler and set level to debug
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

    # add formatter to handler
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add handler to logger
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    logger.propagate = False
```

server file

```
setup_logger("Service")

class ServerV1:
    """Data server V1
    """
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.interface = DataInterfaceV1()
```

some file from project

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger("Service")


def get_shopper_list(data) -> list:
    """get shopper list"""
    user_list = data.get('shoppers', False)
    if not user_list:
        logger.info('"shoppers" field not in request, skipping calculation')
    if not isinstance(user_list, list):
        logger.info('"shoppers" field is not a list, skipping calculation')
        user_list = False
    return user_list
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solutions and realized that standard and google cloud logging can't work together.

```
import logging

import urllib3
import google.cloud.logging




def setup_logger(name: str):
    """Logger"""
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    if name == 'sys_logger':
        # Running on local machine, use standard logging
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    elif name == 'gcloud_logger':
        # Running on Google Cloud, use Google Cloud Logging
        logging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
        logging_client.get_default_handler()
        logging_client.setup_logging()
```